# How to get current solution configuration in vspackage?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vspackage

I'm making Visual Studio package, and I need to know opened solution name and configuration. How can I get this information ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reference to EnvDTE, you can use `dte.Solution` and `dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.ActiveConfiguration`.

Comment: thanks for answer, but i get crash with exception(Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID), after googling i found that it should solution be in x86. Is it so ?

Comment: A VS Package must be compiled as x86. Visual Studio is 32-bit only.

Comment: And for those looking on how to get a reference to the `DTE`, call the `GetService()` method as such: `DTE dte = (DTE)GetService(typeof(DTE));`.