# Using the EnvDTE assembly

Tags: c#, envdte, vspackage

Is it possible to use the [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/envdte.aspx) assembly in a *non-extension* project (e.g. a *Class Library* project)?

If so, how would I access [the ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/envdte.configurationmanager.activeconfiguration.aspx)?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13071175/1316620) answers exactly what I want, but I couldn't get the `dte` object that it uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EnvDTE only works from within Visual Studio, if that's what you mean.

However, you can control Visual Studio programmatically (using COM monikers you can access to a given Visual Studio instance remotely). Check these blog posts here: [How to start Visual Studio programmatically](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516145907/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/03/03/how-to-start-visual-studio-programmatically.aspx) and [How to get DTE from Visual Studio process ID?](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516145327/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2011/08/10/how-to-get-dte-from-visual-studio-process-id.aspx)

Comment: I was hoping that the configuration name I used when building was written in the resulted assembly and, somehow, I wanted to get it at runtime. Or at least get it at compile time and *inject* it to my code. But it seems, as you said, it only works *whithin* Visual Studio.

Comment: @talles: my understanding is that you can use EnvDTE in a T4 template, which would let you inject values into your source at compile time.

Comment: This seems so wrong. I've been using EnvDTE almost exclusively running it from other assemblies or even PowerShell...

Comment: @FilipSkakun - but you do have a Visual Studio at the other end, don't you?

Comment: Exactly - other end. I just want to make sure people are not misled here. :) You can just do stuff like this in PowerShell: `$dte = New-Object -ComObject VisualStudio.DTE; $dte.MainWindow.Visible = $true; $dte.UserControl = $true`
Now I'm here because I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve DTE for existing instances with PowerShell... I've been doing that for years with C#, but PS gets confused with `GetRunningObjectTable`. I know - a separate question...

Comment: @FilipSkakun - yes, that's what I meant by "within Visual Studio", you always need a Visual Studio instance running, but it can be accessed remotely.